# How to make a Mesh to move around in BABYLONJS?

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs

Hi I have Created a Scene in BABYONJS , I am trying to achieve **solor system** in BABYONjs here i have made earth self rotate but i have tried to move arround that does not work any Idea ?

**My Code**

**Self Rotate**

```
scene.beforeRender = function () {    
        newEarth.rotate(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0) , 0.01, 
        BABYLON.Space.WORLD);
};
```

**The need is the earth should move arround**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here below i have a solution using pivot matrix

```
currentMesh.setPivotMatrix(BABYLON.Matrix.Translation(70, 0, 0));
   camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
   scene.registerBeforeRender(function () {
        if (currentMesh) {
            currentMesh.rotate(BABYLON.Axis.Y, Math.PI / 64, 
              BABYLON.Space.LOCAL);
        }
    });
```

try this one.